# Oracle Stored Procedure - does raise_application_error disable the procedure if not trapped?

Tags: oracle

I have a stored procedure in Oracle doing this:

```
SELECT Count(*) INTO v_count_of_rows_bad FROM SCHMEA.TABLE WHERE
KEY1   = v_key1
AND KEY2 = v_key2
AND STATUS IN ('0', 'P', 'N');

IF v_count_of_rows_bad > 0 THEN
   raise_application_error( -20001, 'Status is not ready' );
END IF;
```

The purpose is to prevent the SP from updating the record if the status is one of those three.  There's a batch process that will run against the rows and update the status to Y when complete. Only after this should the SP be allowed to update the row. (I know there's probably a better way to do this, but I'm stuck with some legacy stuff, and another team controls the batch process).

I'm not catching the exception in the stored proc, but rather using it to transfer the text "Status it not ready" to my .NET webservice (written in C#) which is calling the procedure.

The problem is, once the error is encountered, it seems to get stuck.  Even if I manually updated the status to Y in the table, and see that it really did update, when I run my .NET service again, it gives me the error again.   But if I run the SQL that does the create or replace of the stored procedure again, then run the webservice, its no longer "stuck." Or if I merely compile the SP again, that fixes it.  Does anyone know what this could be?

Comment: Assuming that your code is calling your procedure again (i.e. that it is not inadvertently caching the prior result), if the error is being thrown again, then at least one row has a `status` of 0, P, or N with the two keys.  Either the batch process (or your manual update) isn't updating every row or your updates are not visible either because the updates haven't been committed or because of the transaction isolation level of your code has been set to serializable.  It's tough to guess since you haven't posted a reproducible test case.

Comment: @Justin Cave, If it were that the rows had not really updated then rebuilding the stored proc would not fix it.

Comment: Recompiling the code could solve the problem that your code can't see the updates though (either because it is implicitly committing the changes you're making or because it is causing the code using a serializable isolation level to start a new transaction).  It could also be triggering your application to stop caching the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, raising an exception in a stored procedure doesn't cause Oracle to "get stuck". But the exception will be returned to the caller, and the caller will need to handle the exception appropriately, for example, ROLLBACK the current transaction, and close the connection (or return it to the connection pool.)

It's not clear why re-compiling the stored procedure would cause the application to become "unstuck". The information provided is insufficient to definitively explain the behavior you are observing. (As Justin points out in his comments, there are several possibilities (transaction isolation level, uncommitted transactions, implicit commits, resultsets cached, et al.)

Comment: It was the transaction isolation level

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to raise an exception in this case unless you really want to; you can just code the UPDATE so it doesn't do anything if the status is one of the undesirable values:

```
UPDATE A_SCHEMA.SOME_TABLE
  SET SOME_COL = vVALUE,
      SOME_OTHER_COL = vOTHER_VALUE,
      ETC = vBLAH
  WHERE KEY1 = v_key1 AND
        KEY2 = v_key2 AND
        STATUS NOT IN ('0', 'P', 'N');
```

If you need to know if any rows were updated you can use %ROWCOUNT, as in

```
IF SQL%ROWCOUNT > 0 THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows updated');
ELSE
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No rows updated! Run! Run for your lives!!');
END IF;
```

This is almost certainly faster than doing a `SELECT COUNT(*)...` (which can be surprisingly slow) and *then* turning around and doing the `UPDATE`.

Share and enjoy.